# MySQL - Help me to make a query

Tags: mysql

I want to make a query which selects first_name, count(*) from staff, where department_id is unique and it counts the number of peoples with the same name in different departments.

To show this, this is my table:
department_id / first_name / ...other columns

```
1 / Sam  / ...
1 / Sam  / ...
2 / John / ...
2 / Sam  / ...
3 / John / ...
```

So, I should get the result:

```
Sam  / 2
John / 2
```

(Three Sams, but two from them are from the same department, because we count them as a one)

My schema:

```
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| dep_id     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| first_name | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| salary     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name  | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is you need to group by name and department

```
 select count(*),first_name from tableName group by first_name,department_id
```

Comment: can you send me your database schema

Comment: I added. So, by this was I'm getting unique names, but it counts peoples from the same department, but it should count only one person from one department with a specified name

Comment: try this 
select total,first_name from ( select count(*) as total,first_name,department_id from tableName group by first_name,department_id) as alais group by department_id

Comment: Oh, yeah! That works. Can you please describe how it works and why the prev variant not? And I'd like to get sorted output. I tried to add "ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 100" to the subquery, but it didn't work. After that I added it to the main query and I've got dublicate records

Comment: there is a particular use of group by...group by just groups the result based on the columns you pass...the result was in the first query had multiple name with departments,  I wrote another query over that set which grouped the data with department, so it took the last row and grouped the data..that was a turn around, you need to query as per your requirements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70200/discussion-between-bugiz400-and-danyal-sandeelo).